# terra R package functions error that file exists and needs overwrite=T

Tags: r, terra

For the past 2 days I am trying to use the terra R package functions crop(), mask() and project() for simple spatial analyses. However, after 2-3 min of running each of the functions gives the same error

`Error: [<function>] file exists. You can use 'overwrite=TRUE' to overwrite it`

This is the first time this has happened to me using the terra R package and I do not know how to proceed. I am using the CRAN version 1.5-34 and have repeatedly uninstalled and installed it.

At the beginning of my script I have specified options as

`terraOptions(memfrac=0.7, tempdir = "C://Users//myname//OneDrive - Nexus365//Paper3//Scratch",todisk= TRUE, progress=10, overwrite= T)`

Help?

Comment: please show your script, and the output you get where you get it. Also, does this problem go away when you do not set these options?

Comment: this is a bug that was fixed in the development version. `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue today after installing the development version. Any suggestions? Here's my error after specifying "overwrite = T" in writeVector: 

Error: [writeVector] Layer creation failed
In addition: Warning message:
Layer 'ignitions' already exists (GDAL error 1)

Answer (score 1):

As @Robert Hijmans has commented, this is now fixed in the developmental version of terra.

So for now, I have reinstalled terra using the developmental version instead of CRAN and have proceeded.